# Adding verification to jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, tabs

I have setup a demo for my jquery tabs to show you my problem:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4f2hdxd/)

so, I am going to have forms on each of the tabs, what I am wanting to do is add some kind of prevention on the tabs if they have not filled out the fields. So if they try to click on the next tab it only becomes active if they have filled in the info in the first tabs:

```
function checkForm()
   {
       if($("#textbox").val()=='')
       {
          return false
       }
       else
       {
         return true;
       }
    }


$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
   var val = checkForm();
   if(val)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().addClass("current");
       $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
       var tab = $(this).attr("href");
       $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
       $(tab).fadeIn();
   }
   else 
   {
      return false;
   }
 });





 <div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Your details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Additional information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
<div class="tab">

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">

        <label>Company name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
            <br>

        <label>Contact name:</label>    
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
            <br>


        <label>Email address:</label>    
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
            <br>



        <label>Telephone number:</label>    
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
            <br>



        <label>How did you find us?</label>    
        <input type="text" id="textbox">   
            <br>



        <input type="submit" value="Submit">             

    </div>




    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">          

    </div>




    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    3
    </div>




    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    4
        </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannont have more than one HTMLElement with a particular ID !

Just add a `class="required"` for all the input that actually are required, and you can go with this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var currentTab;
  $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
          requiredAreFilled = true,
          tab = $this.attr("href"),
          currentTab = $('.tabs-menu .current').children('a').attr('href');
      $(currentTab).find('.required').each(function(index, elt) {
          if (!$(elt).val()) requiredAreFilled = false;
      });
      if (requiredAreFilled) {
          $this.parent().addClass("current")
              .siblings().removeClass("current");
          $(".tab-content").not(tab).hide();
          $(tab).fadeIn();
      }
  });
});
```

See result there : http://jsfiddle.net/q4f2hdxd/2/

Comment: So, I need a submission button on this also, how do you query the fields if they have not submitted info in all the fields?

Comment: I am sorry I am afraid I don't understand what you are asking.
A submission button on every  tab, right ?
But what do you mean by "query the fields if they have not submitted info" ?

Comment: So, with the code above, it works great, but I need the form to have a submit button to then move to the next tab, and if the fields have not been entered for it to flag that but showing an error to say which fields have not been filed in.

Comment: Well, you could do something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/q4f2hdxd/3/
I leave it here in the comment, because it was not in the initial question. I think I answered the original question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Build a JS validation function something like below to validate all your text boxes.

```
   function checkForm()
   {
       if($("#textbox").val()=='')
       {
          return false
       }
       else
       {
         return true;
       }
    }
```

Then call your check form method from the click event. And if the form validates then move on else cancel the click event.

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
   var val = checkForm();
   if(val)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().addClass("current");
       $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
       var tab = $(this).attr("href");
       $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
       $(tab).fadeIn();
   }
   else 
   {
      return false;
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hi, I have just used the code you have provided but the tabs are still clickable? Am I missing something, because I have used the code provided and it still tells me I am able to click on the tabs and there is no validation happening?

Comment: Is the validation working? If it is try using this event.preventDefault(); instead of just returning false.

Comment: I have just re-submitted my question to show you what I have done...It would be great to show me where I have gone wrong maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/q4f2hdxd/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {

        if (checkForm('form1') === true) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
            var tab = $(this).attr("href");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
            $(tab).fadeIn();
        }


    });
});

function checkForm(form_id) {

    var $fields = $("#"+form_id).find('input');
    var error = false;

    for (i = 0; i < $fields.length; i++) {
        if ( $($fields[i]).val() == "" ) {
            error = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (error === true) {
        $('#'+form_id).find('.error').html('error');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: See this works great, but if you do not put any content in and it shows error, when you go back to the tab the error message still shows?